# Replace Tags HTML

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma página em PHP que exibe POSTS (estilo BLOG).

Só que as vezes eu posto alguns comandos no proprio texto (tags html etc).

Como posso fazer para:

1 -  -> Se tiver algo como alert() ele apenas mostra na página este comando, mas não executa ela.

Obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Para você exibir os elementos HTML, basta você utilizar a função [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo htmlentities("<script>alert('SOpt')</script>");
```

A saída será:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert('SOpt')&lt;/script&gt;
```

E assim o navegador, ao invés de executar o código, apenas o exibirá.

Answer (score -2):

Bom, não sei se entendi muito bem, mas como o alert você teria o console.log().

Em vez de alert('Olá mundo'), você colocaria console.log('Olá mundo'). No caso do Chrome, aperte F12 e abra a guia console. Assim tudo o que enviar pelo console.log será exibido nesta guia de forma silenciosa, assim o usuário não conseguirá ver. Obs, isto serve para códigos em javascript.

Além do console.log, você tem console.warn que exibe o texto em amarelo escuro e com um sinal de exclamação, serve para chamar atenção. Também possuí o console.error que exibe a mensagem que desejar em forma de erros.

Caso queria enviar uma variável do PHP para o console.log, poderia utilizar este código:

```
<?php
    $array = array("um" => 1,"dois" => 2, 3, 4);
    $debug = json_encode($array);
    echo "<script>console.log($debug)</script>";
?>
```